# CodeIgniter and 1and1 - 404 error message

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, shared-hosting

I'm experiencing a similar issue with a 404 error message. 
I'm using CI 2.0.2 and I have a basic shared hosting with 1and1, and my .htaccess located in my website root (/mywebsite/.htaccess) directory and it looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

    AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

In my config.php file I have the following:

```
<?php
$config['base_url']    = 'http://mywebsite.com';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol']    = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

It doesn't matter what I do I keep getting the 404 page not found error :http://d.pr/F2KR

I have spent several hours on looking for a solution to this problem and have not been able to fix it.

Any Suggestions, tips, or an actual answer to this question is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE 1:
I called 1and1 and they told me that it must be a problem with the index.php since that 404 error message is generated by CodeIgniter and not the server. are there other configuration values that I should be looking at?

UPDATE 2:
I found out that there is a case sensitive issue (this is odd since both localhost and server are UNIX/LINUX respectively), if the controller class is called Login, then the path needs to be mysite.com/Login/ it cannot be mysite.com/login/. I'm still not sure how this issue will be resolved, I don't want to re-write a bunch of paths.

**UPDATE 3 (RESOLVED)**: As stated on update 2, the issue was not the .htaccess, but the naming scheme of my models and controllers, more specifically the file names. Apparently on my Mac (dev machine) I can have models called User.php or Login.php and will make no difference if I use upper or lower case in the URL, but as soon as I uploaded my code into 1and1, I kept getting the CI "*404 not found*" error message. My particular solution to the problem was to change all the models and controllers file names to lowercase as suggested on this post http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/129013/#636849.

Comment: Are you sure that mod_rewrite is enabled on your server?  That would definitely cause a 404 error.

Comment: @Onema Please double check your hosting account: based on screenshot you have provided I think that you may have Windows hosting (IIS Server) that has no support for .htaccess files (unless some 3rd party module is installed, like Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite v3 or Helicon Ape, for example). **P.S.** And no need to have `AddType` & `AddHandler` directives inside `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` -- it does not make much sense.

Comment: @Chris Schmitz: I will contact my hosting provider about this.

Comment: @LazyOne The 404 error was generated by CI that is why it is styled like that. I is a linux server, this is the info I got from phpinfo(): Linux infong 2.4 .. GNU/Linux. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Try modifying the first `<if>` to the code above, works for my codeigniter setup.

Not sure about the `AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php`...

Comment: I tried that, and removed the php5 lines, didn't work. those really doesn't matter any more since you can choose the 'global php' you want to use in 1and1. good suggestion tho.

Comment: perfect! it helped me very much and worked without any further issues.

Answer (score 1):

I agree w/Chris, to be sure you have mod_rewrite enabled you can try to change the 404 page:

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

to something else like a dummy page

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 my_dummy_page.html
</IfModule>
```

if you begin to havin the new 404 dummy page it's because you don't have mod_rewrite enabled.

Comment: Yep, it is enabled. I figure that the problem is related to case sensitive uri, so if the controller is called User it looks like this mysite.com/User/. All I care at this point is for the uri to be case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

I use this htaccess on my 1and1 and my CI2 runs fine. Its located in the CI base folder.
Also make sure that your .htaccess has a .(dot) in the name, generally windows removes that dot.

```
Options -Indexes

DirectoryIndex index.php

AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php   

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase   /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.in
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.in/$1 [R=301,L]
```